# Creating and using Custom Cordova IOS plugin for Ionic App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am very new to ionic development. I have an Objective C code that provides some custom functionality using the Camera and I want to use this native code in my ionic app using Cordova. After spending a few hours in the research I concluded that we need to create a Cordova plugin upload it on Github and then add it to our Ionic project. I tried I few demos and read some articles but all seem to be out of date and I am not able to proceed.

It would be really great if someone could guide me with

1. Steps of creating a Cordova plugin with my Objective C code and
2. Steps to use that plugin in my existing ionic app.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Most information should be contained on the related [Cordova website](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html).
Here are some boiled down leads ...
Use [cordova-plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman) to create a cordova plugin like so:

1. Install the package from github:

```sh
npm i -g git+https://git@github.com/apache/cordova-plugman.git
```

2. Use the module to create a plugin like so:

```sh
plugman create --name "test" --plugin_id "test" --plugin_version "0.0.1"
```

3. Change directory to folder "test" and run:

```sh
plugman createpackagejson .
```

4. Add some platform the plugin should support:

```sh
plugman platform add --platform_name "android"
```

This should get you setup with a default plugin. To use the plugin from a Cordova app, change the directory to the app and run:

```sh
cordova plugin add /absolute/path/to/plugin
```

In the `config.xml` of the plugin, inside the following tag, you can specify how the plugin should be accessed during runtime.

```xml
<js-module name="test" src="www/test.js"><clobbers target="cordova.plugins.test" /></js-module>
```

In this case, the file `www/test.js` will be available under `window.cordova.plugins.test`. Reference is the Cordova documentation for the [`plugin.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#js-module). Additional information on how to access native code on iOS can be found in the Cordova documentation for [iOS plugin development](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying. The steps you provided helped me create a cordova plugin but I do not know how to use that plugin in my ionic app